# Can Stable Diffusion be considered a breakthrough for reconstructing images from fMRI data?

Tags: image-processing

https://sites.google.com/view/stablediffusion-with-brain

I recently came across a paper (not yet peer-reviewed) that describes the successful use of Stable Diffusion to reconstruct images based on data collected by fMRI. As I understand it, the computer is given a fuzzy image of what the person is thinking of, along with an order such as "draw a teddy bear on this blurry image." The computer then separates the colors, aligns the pixels, and creates a reconstructed image.

However, I'm not sure if this is a truly new breakthrough or just an incremental advance. The paper states that the algorithm uses only images from the primary visual cortex to calculate z, while c uses images from the secondary cortex along with annotations (not orders, on average 5), and zc combines both representations. The authors also conclude that z is consistent but not semantic.

In order to generat[image]e control images, the paper states that the model was used as image-to-image (z) or text-to-image (c), omitting where necessary. Does this mean that the model has potential applications beyond image reconstruction? Can Stable Diffusion be considered a breakthrough for reconstructing images from fMRI data?

[image]

[image]